# Estimate unknown measurements in time series from other related ones

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, filtering, mathematical-optimization

I need a time series of the angle between two robot arms and I have got measurements of tilt sensors on the arms. (A and B). In an ideal world one tilt sensor minus the other one should give my signal.

But the tilt sensors show a lot of noise and funny peaks, especially when the robot is subjected to vibrations, or moves quickly. I am working offline, so all the data is available at all time. Fortunately I have one (extended) measurement of the tilt sensors and an angle sensor on one robot.

Ideally, I am searching for something like this:

```
Black_Box=Optimize_Black_Box(Result, Input A, Input B) #(compute for extended amount of time)
Result_estimated=Black_Box(Angel A, Angel B)
```

Alternativly I am thinking of something like this:

```
filtfilt(filtfilt(Input A)-filtfilt(Input B))
```

and use a minimizer to optimize the filter parameters....

Any idea about the strategy will be appreciated. 
Greetings
Okapi

Comment: did you try tweaking the sampling rate on the input signals?

Comment: Sadly, the data is recorded with just 10 Hz. The data was not recorded with this idea in mind. The sample rate of my "training" data is 20 Hz... I think reducing the sampling to a value smaller than 10 Hz will do no good...